# Comment author name renders nicely in Chrome, but half blank in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome, cross-browser

In the code below, the `$row["username"]` is the author of a comment.  It renders well in Chrome, but in IE 8, only the top half of it appears.  Any idea how to make it so all of it appears in IE 8?

Thanks in advance,

John

The code:

```
echo "<table class=\"commentecho\">";
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt1 = new DateTime($row["datecommented"], $tzFrom1);  
    $dt1->setTimezone($tzTo1);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td rowspan="3" class="commentnamecount">'.$count++.'.</td>';
    echo '<td class="commentname2"><a href="http://www...com/.../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
    echo '<td rowspan="3" class="commentname1">'.stripslashes($row["comment"]).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="commentname2">'.$dt1->format('F j, Y').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="commentname2a">'.$dt1->format('g:i a').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

The CSS:

```
table.commentecho {
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    width: 600px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px #FFFFFF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;    
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}

table.commentecho td {
   border: 2px solid #fff;  
   text-align: left; 
   height: 14px;
   overflow:hidden;

}

table.commentecho td a{
   padding: 2px;
   color: #004284;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight:bold;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 14px;
}

table.commentecho td a:hover{
   background-color: #004284;
   padding: 2px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight:bold;
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 14px;
}

.commentname2 { width: 120px;
            color: #000000;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname2 a{ width: 120px;
            color: #004284;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;

}

.commentname2 a:hover{ width: 120px;
            color: #004284;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            height: 20px;
            padding-top:0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            vertical-align: top;

}
```

Comment: A couple of tips: 1> you don't need a separate echo for each line of html. Just don't close the quotes and continue the string on the next line. 2> It's a lot cleaner to just go out of PHP mode with ?> for your HTML parts, then go back in with <?php when you need to echo a var or resume other coding.3> if you have to use quotes within double quotes, instead of escaping it with \ just use single quotes. Just pointing these out because I look at my old code and see the same things!

Comment: Also - you don't need to repeat all of the styles for the a:hover - only what's different. In this case, text-decoration:underline. But browsers do that by default, unless you've over-ridden the default in an earlier declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that the TDs are 14px tall, and overflow is hidden, but the commentname2 class is 20px tall.

IE is hiding 6 pixels of it for this reason. If a child element is going to be 20px, make the container at least 20px, or at least remove `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.commentname2 a {
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
    /* all other CSS */
}
```

The zoom: 1 may not be necessary, but sometimes IE needs it to trigger its [hasLayout flag](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) and stop content from getting cut or rendered incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have font-size: 14px; but have several height: 14px; with padding which will count into the height.

Basically, you need to make sure that font size will fit with the other (padding) within the height of the td you have set thus the vertial space set by your CSS cuts off the charters when the font does not fit in.

This is one reason I use em instead of px - it makes the layout easier (to me at least) when considering the box model.

Comment: He specifies the font-size as 11px in commentName2, though.